# Remote server DIR, only part of file name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dir

I want to query three folders (on three separate servers) for a list of client names.

Basically, in each of these folders, I have a bunch of .EXE's that are named as follows:

```
ClientName_ProductName.exe
```

From my main server, I'd like to output JUST the "ClientName" part to a ClientNames.txt file.

Here is what I had so far, but it is pulling ALL information in (all files in the directory):

```
:: Setting  the client names file

set clientnamefile="C:\ClientNames.txt"


:: Copying directory information to ClientNames.txt

dir *_ProductName.exe "\\server1\c$\Program Files (x86)\Folder\" /B > %clientnamefile%
dir *_ProductName.exe "\\server2\c$\Program Files (x86)\Folder\" /B >> %clientnamefile%
dir *_ProductName.exe "\\server3\d$\Program Files (x86)\Folder\" /B >> %clientnamefile%
```

I want to end up with the following inside of a .txt file (which will then be used by another one of my scripts):

```
ClientName1
ClientName2
ClientName3
ClientName4
ClientName5
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to write, dir "\folder\\*_productname.exe"?

Comment: LOL...what, what a fail. That worked and got me the list of ClientName_ProductName.exe for each of those directories. Thanks @MrLister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the internet, changing some things to fit my needs, and also help from MrLister in pointing out my rookie syntax mistake, I was able to get this working.

I now have a single text file which contains only the ClientName portion of my ClientName_ProductName.exe files from three different network locations.

**The code is below:**

```
:: Setting  the client names file
set textfile="C:\Util\TFProAdmin Update\ClientName_Dirty.txt"
set textfile2="C:\Util\TFProAdmin Update\ClientName.txt"

set server1="\\clientimport01\c$\Program Files\Transfinder\TransfinderPro
set server2="\\clientimport02\c$\Program Files (x86)\Transfinder\Routefinder Pro
set server3="\\clientimport03\d$\Program Files (x86)\Transfinder\Routefinder Pro
set fileextension=*_ProductName.exe"
set searchline=_ProductName.exe

:: *********************************************************************************
:: ******************* DO !NOT! CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS POINT ******************* 
:: *********************************************************************************


@Echo off
cls
@Echo.
@Echo *********************************************************
@Echo.
@Echo        Starting client name collection process
@Echo.
@Echo *********************************************************
@Echo.
@Echo off

:: Gathering the list of _ProductName.exe files from each of the import servers and writing it to a 'dirty' (temp) text file
dir %server1%\%fileextension% /B > %textfile%
dir %server2%\%fileextension% /B >> %textfile%
dir %server3%\%fileextension% /B >> %textfile%

:: Cleaning up the original text file to remove _ProductName.exe from each line
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

@Echo. > %textfile2%
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (%textfile%) DO (
  Set "line=%%G" & echo !line:%searchline%=!
) >> %textfile2%

:: Deleting temporary 'dirty' text file
del %textfile%

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the help for `set` in cmd. This gives you options to extract part of an environment variable.

Thus, using a second variable because I don't think that variable expansion works for loop variables, and using the string replacement form.

```
for %i in (\\server1\c$\Program Files (x86)\Folder\*_ProductName.exe) set ii = %i: echo %ii:_ProductName.exe=%
```

(In a script use `%%i` rather than `%i`.)

Probably easier in PowerShell, remembering the matching parameter of `-replace` is a regex so need to escape the period:

```
dir '\\server1\c$\Program Files (x86)\Folder\*_ProductName.exe' `
  | % { $_.Name -replace '_ProductName\.exe', '' }
```

(For a script I would use the full cmdlet names rather than the abbreviations: `Get-ChildItem` and `ForEach-Object` and specify the parameter names.)

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up doing something a little different. See below. @Richard